# VBA to hide entire row if cell in COL A = True

Tags: vba

I have searched to web, looking for VBA code to hide entire row if cell in COL A = True

Is this possible?

Much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried searching "excel vba hide row if cell contains" and clicking on the first link? http://superuser.com/questions/663441/vba-code-to-hide-or-unhide-rows-based-on-a-cell-value

Comment: I can't resist it - it's entirely possible to search the web for your answer. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Darren - I searched but the code seemed overly complicated
I thought it could loop thru each cell like For i = 1 To Rows.Count

Next i    and where value = TRUE hide entire row

I will keep searching

Thanks

I knew it was a stupid Q  :-/

Comment: Not overly complicated.  `1 to Rows.Count ` might run for too long - it would look at all 1048576 rows in turn.  Would be better to find the last row and limit the loop to that.  If column A is only TRUE/FALSE or Empty then `rng.EntireRow.Hidden = rng.Value` should work, where `rng` is used within a `For...Each` loop.  Not sure if you can do it in one hit with some kind of array formula result though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice Darren. Good to know Rows.Count is the long way round. Still learning. Seems I was deducted a point for my Q. Oh shame. Thanks again though for the valuable advice

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cell As Range
For each cell in Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellConstants) '<--| loop through cells with any "constant" (i.e. not resulting out of a formula) value only
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = cell.Value
Next cell
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.

Comment: @Aurora0001, OP's already been given plentiful of links where to grab info about how to hide rows from and hints as to how to code. My contribution is to write one possible implementation out of those links and hints. People here are best helped here when taught how to help themselves.

Comment: Even so, providing some explanation could help the OP (and anyone else who finds the question) to understand what you're doing. Also, it'll probably help to make sure your answers don't get pushed into the review queues (like this one was) if you provide more detailed explanation.

Comment: You, and those who pushed this answer into review queue, didn't read comments below the question that already addressed all (few) issues here touched

Comment: For the record, I didn't push it into the queue (or recommend deletion), and I'm sure you'll understand that you get no context in the review queue - you just get this post standing on its own and from that it appeared to be code-only. I'm sorry that I didn't check the other posts though - it probably would have helped. By the way, it may have just been an automated decision to push your answer into the review queue (I assume there's some sort of heuristic to detect code-only answers). Hopefully this will clear it up for the other reviewers.

Comment: I didn't assume you pushed it into any review queue, since I clearly got you yourself found it there! Not an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are no stupid questions, because questions are simply an inquiry to understanding more of a problem. The issue with your question is that you did not show any evidence of trying to understand a solution on your own.

Morality (and SO rules) aside, as Darren already stated in a comment, you can find a potential solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/663441/vba-code-to-hide-or-unhide-rows-based-on-a-cell-value

You can also apply the solution in the above SU answer to a [loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) and check the entirety of the sheet. There are simpler solutions out there to this particular issue, but it will require (minimal) research.

My suggestion is you start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+loop+through+column+and+hide+rows+based+on+value

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Apologies everyone I seem to have created a storm.
I am very much a novice at VBA, so still learning the right Q to ask
Apologies once again  :(